# How do I put a thermometer on a contribution page?

Tags: contribution-page

My organization occasionally does one-off fundraising drives for specific situations where we need to raise a certain amount of money (e.g. "Send our youth employees to the US Social Forum"). Creating a new contribution page makes sense here. But we'd like to have a thermometer on the page.

Using a personal campaign page would give us a thermometer, but it's an extra hassle to set up, and doesn't quite fit the situation as well  because of the way the PCP creates soft credits.

The contribution page provides a widget with a thermometer that I can embed on *other* sites. I can even embed this widget within the contribution page to obtain a thermometer. But then I get a bunch of superfluous stuff in the widget, like a "Contribute" button which takes people to the page they're on. No good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it works well for you to copy and paste the embed code onto the contribution form, there are just certain redundant bits you'd like to hide.
You could add some generalized global rules for this to your website's css. e.g.

```
form.CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main .crm-contribute-widget h5,
form.CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main .crm-contribute-widget .crm-comments,
form.CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main .crm-contribute-widget .crm-campaign,
form.CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main .crm-contribute-widget .crm-contribute-button-wrapper {
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I've come up with is to generate the widget, edit the code, append the following CSS, and paste into the contribution page's introductory message source:

```
h5#crm_cpid_35_title,
div#crm_cpid_35_comments,
div#crm_cpid_35_campaign,
div#crm_cpid_35_button {
  display: none; 
}
```

This works for me, but I'd like to find a better solution that is more usable by non-technical staff.